# AspNetRoles table not showing custom fields

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have recently extended my AspNetRoles table like this:

```
public class AspNetRoles:IdentityRole
{
        public AspNetRoles() : base() { }
        public String Label { get; set; }
        public String ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public AspNetApplications Application { get; set; }

        public static readonly String SystemAdministrator = "SystemAdministrator";
 }
```

It works fine when I create a new role. However, when I try to extract it to a list like this:

```
var data = dbContext.Roles.ToList();
```

And try to do a search like this:

```
data = data.Where(u => u.Id.ToString().ToLower().Contains(Input.Search.ToLower())).ToList();
```

I can't access the ApplicationId column. Am I missing something?

EDIT:

My dbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, AspNetRoles<string>, string>
{
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsersExtendedDetails> AspNetUsersExtendedDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetApplications> AspNetApplications { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetEventLogs> AspNetEventLogs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("AppStudio")
    {

    }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I have updated my dbContext but now it shows this error: `'IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, AspNetRoles<string>, string>' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments`

Comment: Did you mean `u => u.ApplicationId.ToString()`?

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke, yes. I cannot access the ApplicationId property

Comment: are getting any error or its value null ?

Comment: No, Intellisense doesn't have it and when I add it, I cannot compile the app. So far I can access Id and Name only which are what it originally had.

Comment: have you try with restart your visual studio because you said Intellisense doesn't . :)

Comment: @LaljiDhameliya yes I have. It doesn't work. For some reason when I reference the Roles item it doesn't show my new columns

Comment: Please show what your DbContext looks like.

Comment: @BrendanGreen I've updated the question with my dbcontext

Comment: Since you've customised the `IdentityRole`, you need to include this in your DbContext: `ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, AspNetRoles<string>, string>` (assuming that the PK for your users is a `string`.

Comment: i think dbContext.Roles is IdentityRole? right not AspNetRoles may be you are not access sub class property so please add "AspNetRoles" in your DbContext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell ASP.Net Identity about the custom role table that you want to use.

**Edit**: since the default `IdentityRole` implementation uses a `string` as the PK, the type can be omitted.  Just checking futher on ASP.Net Identity version 2, as soon as you specify a custom `IdentityRole` class, the class declaration needs to include **all** types.

That means you need to declare your `ApplictionDbContext` like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, AspNetRoles, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("AppStudio")
    {
        //note: before this change, if you included the 
        //throwIfV1Schema parameter in the constructor, 
        //it needs to be removed.
    }

    //implementation 
}
```

Note that this assumes that the Primary Key of the users table is a `string`.  If this is not the case, substitute with the applicable type (e.g. a `Guid`).

Comment: The table was generated by entity framework. I just added custom columns to it though? Surprisingly adding AspNetRoles as a DbSet allowed me to access the Application Id

Comment: You don't want to just add your table as a `DbSet`, as this declaration tells ASP.Net Identity that `Roles` is now your `AspNetRoles` custom table.

Comment: This answer causes this error to appear though : The non generic type IdentityDbContext cannot be used with type arguments. My public ApplicationDbContext() : base("AppStudio", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {

        }
also shows errors saying it does not have a constructor that takes 2 arguments.

Comment: Am I supposed to edit the IdentityDbContext as well?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `throwIfV1Schema` parameter?

Comment: Nothing changes if I remove that parameter

Comment: This is my IdentityDbContext class : public class IdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>

Comment: Please update your question with the changes that you made to your ApplicationDbContext class, because your errors message explicity states that  "...does not have a constructor that takes 2 arguments", and we just removed one of the arguments

Comment: You have specified `IdentityDbContext` twice.  It needs to be `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<...> { }`

Comment: I meant I opened up the IdentityDbContext class to show you what the constructor was in case it could help.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still stuck on this error with the constructor

Comment: Do you have any other DbContext classes in this project?  It's definitely this one that is causing the compiler error?  Because you are only passing one argument to the base constructor.

Comment: No other dbcontext classes in this project. I noticed that the IdentityDbContext that I'm referencing does not have a constructor that accepts your answer. Should I create one there?

Comment: See update to answer.  I think you might have had multiple compile time errors.  I verified the sample code provided in my own project.

Comment: Your answer compiled properly. Do I still leave AspNetRoles in?

Comment: Yes - you have custom properties that you've added to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `AspNetRoles` to your `IdentityDbContext`.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, AspNetRoles, string>
{
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsersExtendedDetails> AspNetUsersExtendedDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetApplications> AspNetApplications { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetEventLogs> AspNetEventLogs { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("AppStudio", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry why would I add AspNetRoles there? Also, what is that string next to AspNetRoles?

Comment: `IdentityDbContext` will get to know that you are using your `AspNetRoles` as roles table.

Comment: This answer causes this: : The non generic type IdentityDbContext cannot be used with type arguments. My public ApplicationDbContext() : base("AppStudio", throwIfV1Schema: false) { } also shows errors saying it does not have a constructor that takes 2 arguments.